# json recursive object update

Tags: json, python-3.x, recursion

I'm working on a json schema parsing script.
Since I don't know what kind of json schema I can expect, meaning how many nesting levels I've taking a look into recursive data manipulation.
After some research I've come up with the following:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

jsonString = '{"transportation": {"airplane": {}, "car": {}, "boat": {}}}'

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonString)

dataObj = ['airplane','car','boat']

dataProp = ['airplane','fly'],['car','drive'],['boat','sail'],['airplane','pilot'],['car','driver'],['boat','sailer']

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(dataObj, columns=['object'])

dfProp = pd.DataFrame(dataProp, columns=['object','property'])

#updating nested JSON
def update_panel_json(input_json, target_key, update_value):
    if type(input_json) is dict and input_json:
        for key in input_json:
            if key == target_key:
                input_json[key] = update_value
            update_panel_json(input_json[key], target_key, update_value)

    elif type(input_json) is list and input_json:
        for entity in input_json:
            update_panel_json(entity, target_key, update_value)


#add properties object to JSON
for index, row in dfProp.iterrows():
    properties =  { "properties": { row['property']: {"type":"string"} }}
    target = row['object']
    update_panel_json(jsonObj, target, properties)

print(jsonObj)
```

This works pretty well for the underlying objects.

Output:

```
{'transportation': {'airplane': {'properties': {'pilot': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'car': {'properties': {'driver': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'boat': {'properties': {'sailer': {'type': 'string'}}}}}
```

However once the root object also has properties the json objects seems to be overwritten only containing the root object with the last property.

Input:

```
dataProp = ['transportation','someproperty'],['airplane','fly'],['car','drive'],['boat','sail'],['airplane','pilot'],['car','driver'],['boat','sailer']
```

Output:

```
{'transportation': {'properties': {'someproperty': {'type': 'string'}}}}
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned it up a bit for easy debugging. I hope it'll give you an idea of how you can handle it:

```
dataProp = (
    ['airplane', 'fly'],
    ['car', 'drive'],
    ['boat', 'sail'],
    ['airplane', 'pilot'],
    ['car', 'driver'],
    ['boat', 'sailer']
)
obj = {'transportation': {'airplane': {}, 'car': {}, 'boat': {}}}


def update_panel_json(obj, target_key, update_value):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == target_key:
                obj[key].setdefault('properties', {}).update(update_value)
            update_panel_json(value, target_key, update_value)

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for entity in obj:
            update_panel_json(entity, target_key, update_value)


for key, prop in dataProp:
    new_prop = {prop: {"type": "string"}}
    update_panel_json(obj, key, new_prop)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    'transportation': {
        'airplane': {
            'properties': {
                'fly': {'type': 'string'},
                'pilot': {'type': 'string'}
            }
        },
        'boat': {
            'properties': {
                'sail': {'type': 'string'},
                'sailer': {'type': 'string'}
            }
        },
        'car': {
            'properties': {
                'drive': {'type': 'string'},
                'driver': {'type': 'string'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```